# Visual studio dll creating troubleshooting

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll, dllexport

I'm trying to create a simple dll with one external method, but VS genarates nothing but `obj` file when `dll` is needed

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I don't understand, what exactly. I crated standard dll empty project in VS and added two files.

main.h

```
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

EXPORT int sq(int x);
```

main.c

```
#include "main.h"

int sq(int x)
{
    return (x*x);
}
```

Config seems to be valid too
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's my fault.

As you can see on screenshot, dll is generated to `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\`, that means `debug` or `release` folder in solution directory, not project directory. You shold change this path to `.\$(Configuration)\` to get expected result.